# Slow backup routine message in Starcounter

Tags: database, in-memory-database, starcounter, nosql

I have Starcounter installed on my laptop (i7 mobile). Checking the logfile I found that I had several messages like this:

> Memory manager unable to acquire the SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME privilege. Applying slow backup routine

Why does this happen? If this affects the performance is there some way I can improve the installation to avoid this problem, or is this something that will only occur outside a server installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Memory manager unable to acquire the SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME privilege. Applying slow backup routine

This is a warning message. It means that the backup will slow. It happens if the code host `sccode.exe` is run in not elevated mode (without Administrative privilege), which is normal case for Personal server and development environment.

This message will show performance problem in the case of running System server, i.e., in production.

The message should not appear if `sccode.exe` process runs in elevated mode. Note, that in this case all Starcounter processes and Visual Studio (if used) should be run in elevated mode.